# mutliple conditions on single switch case

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a switch case 'or' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207002/how-to-use-a-switch-case-or-in-php)

Is it possible to have multiple conditions on single switch case for example

```
switch($device) {
  case 'blackberry':
  break;
  case 'iphone' || 'ipod' || 'android':
  break;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with the syntax you are suggesting, you'd have to create multiple cases that point to the same action, for example:

```
switch($device) {
  case 'blackberry':
    blackberryFunction();
    break;
  case 'iphone':
  case 'ipod':
  case 'android':
    nonBlackberry();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Here's a working example: http://ideone.com/SGXrA

Answer (score 6):

```
switch($device) {
  case 'blackberry':
  break;
  case 'iphone':
  case 'ipod':
  case 'android':
  do_something();
  break;
}
```

As per the comment below I will elaborate a little bit.

The break statement breaks the execution of a switch statement and exits. So, if you had

```
case "iphone":
do_iphone();
case "ipod": 
do_ipod();
break;
```

(note the missing break between two cases). Both do_iphone(); and do_ipod(); will execute (in order). So, basically what we are doing is a "hack" where the engine goes to the case iphone, and executes (nothing to execute in our original case) and moves ahead to ipod and so on.

Comment: Correct.  I think you could elaborate as to why so MrDoh will understand why not having a break between the three conditions is what he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch($device) {
  case 'blackberry':
  break;
  case 'iphone':
  case 'ipod':
  case 'android':
      //handle all three here
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply use multiple case statements under one another -

```
switch($device){
    case 'blackberry':
    //implementation
    break;
    case 'iphone':
    case 'ipod':
    case 'android':
    //implementation
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ‘stacking’ the case statements is enough:

```
switch($device) {
    case 'blackberry':
        break;
    case 'iphone':
    case 'ipod':
    case 'android':
      break;
}
```