# Making use of a fall-through switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

While researching for better ways to make use of a `switch` statement, I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207002/how-to-use-a-switch-case-or-in-php) example. I wanted to do something similar, but with a twist:

```
switch($status)
{
 case "a":
 case "b":
  echo "start execute code for case a and b";
 case "a":
  echo "continue to execute code for case a only";
 case "b":
  echo "continue to execute code for case b only";
 case "a":
 case "b":
  echo "complete code execution for case a and b";
 break;
 case "c":
  echo "execute code for case c";
 break;
 case "d":
  echo "execute code for case d";
 break;
 case "e":
  echo "execute code for case e";
 break;
 case "f":
  echo "execute code for case f";
 break;
 default:
  echo "execute code for default case";
}
```

Yes, the above obviously doesn't work out as planned because case "a" will fall-through through until it hits a `break`. I just want to know whether there is a way to do this elegantly without repeating too much code.

Comment: This is usually called fall-through; I don't think I've seen it called  "cascade" until now.

Comment: I've never seen a switch statement with duplicate cases.

Comment: Multiple cases work fine in PHP afaik.

Comment: It's `default:`, not `case default:`

Comment: Getting "clever" is a bad idea.  The kind of thing you are trying to do will make your code harder to understand and is very likely to lead to very hard-to-find bugs down the road.  Keep it simple.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I think would be an elegant solution:

```
switch($status)
{
 case "a":
 case "b":
  echo "start execute code for case a and b";
  if($status == "a") echo "continue to execute code for case a only";
  if($status == "b") echo "continue to execute code for case b only";
  echo "complete code execution for case a and b";
 break;
 case "c":
  echo "execute code for case c";
 break;
 case "d":
  echo "execute code for case d";
 break;
 case "e":
  echo "execute code for case e";
 break;
 case "f":
  echo "execute code for case f";
 break;
 default:
  echo "execute code for default case";
}
```

I am not trying to invent anything new here. Just trying to learn from the experiences of everyone here. Thanks to all who provided me with answers.

Comment: Don't know why this isn't ranked higher. This is the simplest solution and also the most legible for future maintainers of the code.

Answer (score 6):

Once a `case` is matched, PHP will ignore any further `case` statements and execute ALL code until either the switch is closed (`}`) or a `break` is encountered. `break` will also terminate the switch, so what you want is not possible.

Comment: It is certainly *possible*; the OP just has to use if/elseif/else.

Comment: @NullUserException: which'd just make things even more illegible. Might as well just stick with if/then/else to begin with.

Comment: That's what I meant: just use if/elseif/then, no switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct switch statement usage.

You should replace your switch with a series of if statements.

```
if($status == a || $status == b ) {
   echo "start execute code for case a and b";
   if(status == a) {
      echo "continue to execute code for case a only";
   }
   else {
      echo "continue to execute code for case b only";   
   }
   echo "complete code execution for case a and b";
}
else if ($status == c) {
   echo "execute code for case c";  
}
...
...
else {
   echo "execute code for default case";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no how in the would `$status` can be `=` `a` AND `b` except if its a `array` i kno what you want to do  and this is my prove of concept

```
function runSwitch($status) {

    if (in_array ( "a", $status ) && in_array ( "b", $status )) {
        echo "start execute code for case a and b" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (in_array ( "a", $status )) {
        echo "continue to execute code for case a only" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (in_array ( "b", $status )) {
        echo "continue to execute code for case b only" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (in_array ( "c", $status )) {
        echo "execute code for case c" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (in_array ( "d", $status )) {
        echo "execute code for case d" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (in_array ( "e", $status )) {
        echo "execute code for case e" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (in_array ( "f", $status )) {
        echo "execute code for case f" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (in_array ( "c", $status ) && in_array ( "f", $status )) {
        echo "continue to execute code for case c AND f only" . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

**Example 1**

```
$status = array (
        "a" 
);

runSwitch($status);
```

Output

```
continue to execute code for case a only
```

**Example 2**

```
$status = array (
        "a" , "b"
);


runSwitch($status);
```

Output

```
start execute code for case a and b
continue to execute code for case a only
continue to execute code for case b only
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your help, but $status is a single character string, not an array. I think I know how to do it. I am just amuse at the kind of response I am getting by others.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B said what you're trying (at least with a switch) can't be done. Fortunately a good way to remove duplicate code is to define methods, that way code common to both a and b can be called when required.