# PHP switch statement showing file type meaning

Tags: php

The input **$filetype** is the file extension, so if we say it's PHP $def should be equal to "Web".
But the output is just "Image" no matter what filetype is in the input.

```
$filetype = "PHP";
switch(strtolower($filetype)) {
    case ("jpeg" || "jpg" || "png" || "ico" || "gif" || "svg" || "ps" || "psd" || "tif" || "tiff" || "ai" || "bmp"):
        $def = 'Image';
        break;
    case ("aif" || "cda" || "mid" || "midi" || "mp3" || "mpa" || "ogg" || "wav" || "wma" || "wpl"):
        $def = 'Audio';
        break;
    case ("7z" || "arj" || "deb" || "pkg" || "rar" || "gz" || "tar.gz" || "z" || "zip"):
        $def = 'Archive';
        break;
    case ("bin" || "dmg" || "iso" || "toast" || "vcd"):
        $def = 'Disc';
        break;
    case ("csv" || "dat" || "db" || "dbf" || "log" || "mdb" || "sav" || "sql" || "tar" || "xml"):
        $def = 'Data';
        break;
    case ("apk" || "bat" || "cgi" || "pl" || "com" || "exe" || "gadget" || "jar" || "py" || "wsf"):
        $def = 'Executable';
        break;
    case ("fnt" || "fon" || "otf" || "ttf"):
        $def = 'Font';
        break;
    case ("asp" || "aspx" || "cer" || "cfm" || "css" || "htm" || "html" || "js" || "jsp" || "part" || "php" || "rss" || "xhtml"):
        $def = 'Web';
        break;
    case ("key" || "odp" || "pps" || "ppt" || "pptx"):
        $def = 'Presentation';
        break;
    case ("c" || "class" || "cpp" || "cs" || "h" || "java" || "sh" || "swift" || "vb"):
        $def = 'Programming';
        break;
    case ("ods" || "xlr" || "xls" || "xlsx"):
        $def = 'Spreadsheet';
        break;
    case ("3g2" || "3gp" || "avi" || "flv" || "h264" || "m4v" || "mkv" || "mov" || "mp4" || "mpg" || "mpeg" || "rm" || "swf" || "vob" || "wmv"):
        $def = 'Video';
        break;
    case ("doc" || "docx" || "odt" || "pdf" || "rtf" || "tex" || "txt" || "wks" || "wps" || "wpd"):
        $def = 'Document';
        break;
    default:
        $def = '';
}
echo $def;
```

How do i get the correct $def output from the switch?

Comment: Please be sure your question contains a [mcve]. If phpfiddle ever goes away then your question loses all value to future visitors.

Comment: Post your code **here**, not on an external site.

Comment: @j08691 It's minimal, complete and the example is linked.

Comment: @ThomasBang get ready for downvotes then 3:

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton My code was too long for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ThomasBang No, the problem is, your question was too short. And not actually a question, as I don't even see a question mark.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Everything is corrected now.

Comment: Your code example needs to be **in your question**, not only on another site.

Comment: @ThomasBang Thanks :) I removed my downvote. You know, I've never seen anyone use that markup before (`("var" || "var2")`) until today, and this is the 2nd post I've seen it on. Is this actually valid?

Comment: @j08691 It was in the question at the time you posted that.

Comment: Thomas, the same question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207002/how-to-use-a-switch-case-or-in-php and has a good explanation.

Comment: @Jase you should hit the "flag" button under the post, and click "a duplicate", and provide the URL there. It will help out our moderators and higher rep people :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I was replying to the OP

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks man! I'd never done that before!

Comment: @jase Thank you for marking it :) I tried to do a search and couldn't find a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch case conditions seems to be wrong. Use it like shown below

```
$filetype = "PHP";

 switch(strtolower($filetype)) {
case 'jpeg';
    case 'jpg';
    case 'png';
         $def = 'image';
    break;
     case 'asp';
    case 'php';
         $def = 'web';
     break;
     default:
      $def = '';
      break;

 }
echo $def; // web
```